# Multiple docker containers resolving each others on the same host

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, saml, saml-2.0

Some background: I am currently working on a SAML test environment with Docker for my Identity Provider (IdP) and Service Provider (SP).

In a nutshell:

1. The IdP should be able to contact the SP.
2. The SP should be able to contact the IdP.
3. The user on Docker (for Mac) should be able to browse both IdP and SP.

Having the IdP and SP in docker-compose generates a name resolution error as those 2 services will be contacting each other based on their services names.
However, the browser is not able to contact the them based on their docker's names.

Basically I'd like to have a DNS that works for both my machine and the docker container. 
How would you set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1**:

Having the IdP and SP in docker-compose generates a name resolution error as those 2 services will be contacting each other based on their services names.

**Answer**:

(1) You can configure your local DNS server (or a host file) and HAProxy to map IdP and SP to the same IP address with different external ports. For example,

```
https://idp.example.com --> 10.10.40.10:8443

https://sp.example.org --> 10.10.40.10:2443
```

(2) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building a Shibbolth SAML IdP and Shibboleth SAML SP using Docker Container.

- Shibboleth SAML IdP is responsible for identity federation.
- OpenLDAP is responsible for identity authentication.
- Shibboleth SAML SP is used to protect a demo application.

**Question #2**:

However, the browser is not able to contact the them based on their docker's names.

**Answer**:

(1) You can NOT use a web browser to communicate with either IdP or SP based on their docker's names.

(2) You can use a web browser to communicate with IdP and SP based on their IP address/Port natively (without HAProxy).

You can [build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) and then follow the instruction to use a web browser to communicate with IdP and SP based on their IP address/Port or domain name/port.

(3) You can use a web browser to communicate with IdP and SP based on their domain name with DNS and HAProxy.

**Question #3**:

Basically I'd like to have a DNS that works for both my machine and the docker container. How would you set this up?

**Answer**:

SAML relies on a web browser to redirect SAML request from SP to IdP and then redirect SAML response from IdP to SP.

(1) You run SAML IdP and SAML SP on different machines. Thus you do NOT need to use HAProxy to map different Docker external ports to different external port of the same physical machine.

(2) You only need to configure DNS to map the IP address of two different physical machines (which run SAML IdP and SAML SP respectively) to different domain name (such as idp.example.com and sp.example.org).

For the testing environment, you can just modify the local host file of the local machine of your web browser to map different IP address to different domain name without configuring the DNS server.

For example, if you use to a web browser/Windows 10 machine to access SAML IdP and SAML SP, you can edit the host file "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" to add the following IP address mapping

```
10.10.40.10 idp.example.com 
10.10.40.11 sp.example.org
```